# jquery json parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I parse this json with jQuery?

```
DayEvents: [{
      "0": "886",
      "event_id": "886",
      "1": "5029",
      "user_id": "5029",
      "2": "Professional",
      "user_type": "Professional",
      ...
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with php ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*The term "parsing" is a bit misplaced since this is already in JSON format. You don't need to parse it, but just to access it. If it were a large String in JSON format then you indeed need to parse it into an useable JSON object first before accessing.*

This JSON contains one property, the `DayEvents`, which in turn contains an array `[]`. You can access properties using dot `.` operator. You can get an array item at the given index using `[index]` where zero `0` denotes the first item.

```
var json = { DayEvents : [{"0":"886","event_id":"886","1":"5029","user_id":"5029","2":"Professional","user_type":"Professional" }]};
var firstDayEvent = json.DayEvents[0];
```

The array in turn contains an object `{}`. Or maybe more than one? You can have more than one items in an array, you should then see `[{}, {}, {}, ...]` and you could then access each item in an loop like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.DayEvents.length; i++) {
    var dayEvent = json.DayEvents[i];
    // ...
}
```

A single day event object has several properties: `0`, `event_id`, `1`, `user_id`, `2`, etc. You cannot access properties starting with a number using dot `.` operator, you would then like to use the brace notation:

```
var zero = firstDayEvent['0'];
var eventId = firstDayEvent.event_id;
var one = firstDayEvent['1'];
var userId = firstDayEvent.user_id;
var two = firstDayEvent['2'];
// ...

alert(eventId); // 886
alert(two); // Professional
```

To learn more about JSON, check [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON).

Comment: I wonder why this was down-voted. Seems to be more what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Well, I've got to give you a +1, because the answer that everyone is voting for doesn't make any sense to me. It's just a copy/paste of an example from the docs.

Comment: +1 simply cause this is a great answer for a beginner! well explaned!

Comment: For some reason i was getting alerts about this it seems it was me that downvoted it, i cant remember doing this :/ i upvoted anyways. sorry :(

Answer (score 7):

Stolen from [.parseJSON() doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

**Example:**

Parse a JSON string.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Your example code seems to be an object already. You would have the put braces around the whole thing to use and parse it with `parseJSON`.

Comment: Note that the OP will need to add braces to make the JSON well-formed.

Comment: @jAndy - Please explain. `parseJSON()` takes a string, right? So how does this answer apply to the question?

Comment: What does OP refer to, you and Patrick both used the term, is it an acronym for something?

Comment: @Simon: parsing is transforming one unuseable format into another useable format. If it were a large string (with leading and trailing quote) then you couldn't access it by `jsonObj.someProperty`, so you would like to parse it first. But the code piece the OP posted is already in JSON, he just don't know how to access it.

Comment: @patrick: I'm assuming that the OP means just like that, parsing a `JSON` string into a `javascript` object. His example code is maybe missleading, but I stick to what he described `"How do I parse this json with jQuery?"`

Comment: @BalusC - no you misunderstand. I didn't know what the acronum *OP* stood for. I 've just worked out that it must mean Original Poster (i.e. The person who posted the original message). Acronyms are great - when you know what they mean. TTFN :-)

Comment: @Simon: Oh you went offtopic, nevermind. @jAndy: it's however a pretty common misphrase. Regardless, let's see what the OP says after all.

Comment: @jAndy - I may be wrong, but I think the opposite is true. I think it is a mis-use of the word `parse`. Because OP already has a valid JSON object, there's no need to parse. I think OP may want to access properties.