# Issue in accessing JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Am facing issue in accessing the JSON object : 
JSON Object am receiving is :

```
{"71":"Heart XXX","76":"No Heart YYYY"}
```

I tried to get the value of 71 and 72 separately and use it ...

but am getting some compile time issue   as :
**Syntax error on token ".71", delete this token**

**Code:**

```
var map=$("#jsonText").val();
    alert(map);
    var  obj=jQuery.parseJSON(map);
    alert("JSON ::"+obj.71);
```

If am printing obj , am able to view `[Object Object]`

Can any one out there please help me to find the mistake i did ..I know the question above is asked in many threads in **SO** . Below are the few threads i found , but failed when i attempted to implement it ..

[jquery json parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005606/jquery-json-parsing)

Also tried using the Jquery tutorial given in

[Jquery JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Its working fine if the key is a String but getting the above error if  its a number ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
alert("JSON ::" + obj[71]);
```

"71" isn't a valid property identifier: an identifier should start with a letter, the underscore or the dollar sign. You can avoid this problem using square brackets instead.

**Note**: everything that's put between square brackets is converted into strings. Even functions, DOM elements or regular expressions: they're all converted with their `toString` methods, or their superclass' `toString`.

So `71` there is converted into `"71"`. If you want a little more performance you can directly use the latter. If you don't need it, you can cut some key presses with just `71`.

Comment: thanks a lot Max ... it worked like a charm ... if you dont min can you help me out how to do it dynamically ... please refer some links .... kind of stuff

Comment: It is a valid property name. It isn't a valid identifier. (And dot notation access of properties requires the use of an identifier, while square bracket access uses strings).

Comment: @Quentin "Identifier", yes, I had temporary amnesia :D

Answer (score 4):

Use instead

```
alert("JSON ::"+obj["71"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the rules or `javascript` a `identifier` should not start by a number so if it starts by a number or for that matter contains spaces and other special charcters then you should access it by using the `[]` operator and not by `.` operator
so `obj.71` is invalid but `obj["71"]` is

Comment: It is a valid property name. It isn't a valid identifier. (And dot notation access of properties requires the use of an identifier, while square bracket access uses strings).

Answer (score 0):

try using this site:

http://json.parser.online.fr/