# Parsing PHP Json Object using jQuery.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using jQuery's AJAX functionality - and I get a response back just fine, but for some odd reason I cannot parse the information inside of it!

I am calling the following:

```
console.log(results);   
console.log(results.data);
```

And what I get is:

```
{"data":[{"member":"asdfasdf","status":"Invalid Email"}]}
undefined
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo Uri::base();?>ajax/add_members/organization",
    data: { 
        organization_id: <?php echo $organization->id;?>,
        members: $('#members').val(), 
        position: $('#position').val() 
    }
}).done(function (results) {
    // lets add them to the table
    console.log(results);   
    console.log(results.data);  
});
```

UPDATE: `dataType: 'json',` was required!

Comment: Could you provide an example of your ajax call setup? That should work fine as long as you specify the `dataType` to be json.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005606/jquery-json-parsing

Comment: posted my jquery , ill try to add datatype, and ill look at that answer too

Comment: Adding `dataType: 'json',` should ensure that jQuery automatically parses the response into an object. Likewise, using `$.parseJSON` manually on the response (if it is a string) will also yield the same object.

Comment: Set the appropriate headers (ie: `Content-type: application/json`) and jQuery should be able to handle it automatically.

Comment: the first comment worked perfect! just added datatype json and boom!

Comment: @user1212047 jQuery's default `dataType` is "intelligent guess," so with the appropriate headers you shouldn't even have to add a datatype to your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you have retrieved the string successfully in `results` doesn't mean it is already an object.  You need to parse the JSON string into an object (this can be done as a shortcut depending on your actual method of calling (i.e `getJSON`).

You might need to do something like this to actually get an object.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```